# Open multiple section at once using standard <lightning:accordion> component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

Using the standard component `<lightning:accordion>` is it possible to open multiple sections together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far it's not possible. If you look at the [Lightning Components Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm&type=5), you'll see that "lightning:accordion (multiple open sections)" is on the roadmap for Winter'19.

If you can't wait, the other option is to use the [accordion's markup from SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/#content) to create your own component out of it.

Comment: From my understanding this wasn't delivered in summer 18'. Am I correct?

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 0):

allow-multiple-sections-open is the tag that simply you can add in the markup